# Problem uploading multiple images in database with single column

Tags: php, html, file-upload

This is my code for uploading multiple images, but in this code I am having a problem:

Images upload successfully into the upload directory but in the database it is uploading  a single image

Here is my php code and my connection and inserting code already established:

```
$uploads_dir = '../property_images';
foreach ($_FILES["R_Prop_Images"]["error"] as $key => $error) {
    if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        $tmp_name = $_FILES["R_Prop_Images"]["tmp_name"][$key];
        // basename() may prevent filesystem traversal attacks;
        // further validation/sanitation of the filename may be appropriate
        $R_Prop_Images = basename($_FILES["R_Prop_Images"]["name"][$key]);
        move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$uploads_dir/$R_Prop_Images");
    }
}
```

Here is the html code

```
<span class="btn_upload"> 
  <input type="file" id="imag" title="" name='R_Prop_Images[]' class="input-img" multiple />

  <span>UPLOAD FILES</span
  </span>
```

Comment: You mentioned a problem with the database but did not show any database code. That makes it difficult to help you. As per [ask] please provide a [mre] of the issue. As you are new, please also take the [tour] to learn more about stackoverflow. You can [edit] your question. Thanks

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<input>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-input-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Answer (score 1):

You can store the values of multiple different files in a json field

Your modified code can look like this:

```
$uploadedList = [];

$uploads_dir = '../property_images';
foreach ($_FILES["R_Prop_Images"]["error"] as $key => $error) {
    if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        $tmp_name = $_FILES["R_Prop_Images"]["tmp_name"][$key];
        // basename() may prevent filesystem traversal attacks;
        // further validation/sanitation of the filename may be appropriate
        $R_Prop_Images = basename($_FILES["R_Prop_Images"]["name"][$key]);

        $fileFullPath = "$uploads_dir/$R_Prop_Images";
        move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $fileFullPath);
        $uploadedList[] = $fileFullPath;

    }
}


$stringToInsertIntoDatabase = json_encode($uploadedList);
```

then you can store the $stringToInsertIntoDatabase json string variable to the database column;

Comment: thinks for replying brother but still facing issue database store successfully show but not showing in mysql database image also upload local directory folder but MySQL database not inserted

Comment: You only displayed the codes related to uploading the file. Please put the codes for inserting into the database so that I can help you better